# Fastest C conditions execution

Tags: c, if-statement, microcontroller

Today I stumbled upon one simple part of code and I would like to know more people opinion.
What would be the fastest code to evaluate this graph

[image]

Comment: Just write the conditionals in code.

Comment: Looks like O(c) to me, no matter how you write it.

Comment: You need to know the relative probabilities of each branch.

Comment: @PaulR Why? Looks to me like no matter which way it runs there are exactly two tests and 1 or 0 assignments.

Comment: @Jonah: you can make the test order more pipeline-friendly if you know the probabilities, e.g. if i = 0 is the most likely outcome you might perform the tail == 0 test first even though it might not be needed.

Comment: @PaulR I still see that requiring two conditionals needing to be true: i > 65 && tail != 0

Comment: @Jonah: that's an overly simplistic view when it comes to pipelined processors, although if the OP is using a low end micro-controller this may be a moot point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as the fastest code to evaluate this graph. It depends on the processor architecture. What can be faster on one architecture, will be slower on another, or not even possible.

Nowadays, the compilers excel at block optimizations, and you should write the code as natural as you can and let the compiler decide what "the fastest" means. If the compiler doesn't have an optimization option, the best way to handle this type of conditions is to use 'conditional move' instructions, because they do not stall the pipeline, but this is very much specific to certain architectures.